# Is there a way to narrow a type in the same block scope?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to narrow a type without introducing a new block scope:

```
type OptionalUser = Request & { user?: User }
type RequiredUser = Request & { user: User }

function handler(request: OptionalUser) {
  isAuthenticated(request) // adds user to request, throws if it can't add it
  request.user // request is now RequiredUser, same block scope as isAuthenticated
}
```

Is there a way to type `isAuthenticated` in such a way that the type of `request` is narrowed down in the same block scope of handler? I know I could use a function that returns a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) but then the narrowed type would only exist inside the block scope of an `if` statement. And if I were to have multiple functions like this it would cause a block scope hell.

Comment: See [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As caTS says it, assert functions are the way to go.

```
type User = {};

type OptionalUser = Request & { user?: User }
type RequiredUser = Request & { user: User }

function handler(request: OptionalUser) {
  isAuthenticated(request) // asserted
  request.user // User
}

function isAuthenticated(request: OptionalUser): asserts request is RequiredUser {
  if (request.user === undefined) {
    throw new Error("No user");
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gXwNwFgBQBokUA8mMAJYD2AdgIYA28SqUAShAI4CuEcwKADIMUHgkQB+AFywJUTEXDROvSoggATFsjSq+A4aPFJZOhQQIAzHrQDGVOlAAW9WpsZIAFBt79gsuSODMwSAJQYBFBQvgbAAHQmiFFQAPSp0ZlQAHqSlvjRlHAAgjzAzhC0VHb0wFo+3HERKbH+ifIp6VnRuQSKhPg29sFQRaXlldW19a0CgRQ0ITphsvRwEsBwMY3+o1v66lrm6CmUVlANfgLtrCh3Yu4QVpS0WhEnBZnliNQA7lCvf4AUUQP0QXgARAA5ahiCQQsJ4T79TBAA)

Comment: Thanks Matthieu and caTS! Did not know about Assertion Functions. I understand that solves the issue how I described it. Unluckily for me, isAuthenticated returns a promise and I think that's not a supported use case, right?

Comment: @Loque no, it's not compatible but you could split it in 2 functions! Btw this is by design https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34636